# Ruby on Rails 4 adding CRUD

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, frameworks, crud

This is my current situation: 
ShoeDeal/

- app/controller/

  - shoe_controller.rb
- app/model/

  - customer.rb
  - item.rb
  - order.rb
- app/views/shoe/

  - index.html.erb
- db/migrate/

  - create_customers.rb
  - create_items.rb
  - create_orders.rb

I’m making a simple ShoeDeals App where your can select a pair of shoes that you want to purchase and add to a shopping cart. i just kinda found out that ruby has a CRUD terminal command (  rails generate scaffold  )  but i already started manually creating the files list. Can i still run this code to finish where i left off?

Answer (score 0):

Generating scaffold files for an existing model/controller etc will create the standard files where they don't exists and skip the ones that do. You can temporarily rename your existing files and inspect/merge the generated code into your existing classes.

Comment: this really helped. Thanks @errata!